# PyCharm import MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, pycharm, mysql-python

I am trying

```
import MySQLdb as mdb
```

on PyCharm and get the error:

```
ImportError: No module named MySQLdb
```

From the PyCharm-preference, cannot find MySQLdb to import.
pymysql was successfully installed on PyCharm though.
 Suggestions ? Thank you very much.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What makes you think that module exists?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `pymysql` installing through PyCharm instead of MySQLdb. It's a drop-in replacement for it.

**Documentation:**  https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL

Comment: Upvoted. Thanks a lot for answering .... pymysql was already successfully installed on PyCharm, but still cannot import mysqldb.