# Unable to connect to MySQL database through PyCharm

Tags: python, mysql, pycharm

I'm a complete beginner here and I'm developing a web application with python-flask and I want to start using a database in my web application. The picture below shows that when I wanted to tested the connection it became error and this makes me unable to connect to the database. Can someone help me? By the way I'm using PyCharm as IDE to code all this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIDgN.png

Answer (score 0):

if you are using flask you can use it like this.
`import os`
`from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy`
`dbURL   = 'mysql+pymysql://rootUser:RootPassword@127.0.0.1/dbname'

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL', dbURL)`

pls leave a comment if this do work or not.

Comment: Hi Jay, did you take a look at the image I attached? I wanted to make connection using pycharm

Comment: ow.. why did you use jdbc ? There is many drivers for mysql connection and python.

Comment: because i'm using the database through pycharm

Comment: you can look on this one. there is an answer that is quite similar to your problem. here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39499387/pycharm-import-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

In the image attached to your post, there is a small hint under the JDBC URL input box :

> Overrides settings above

So you should remove the jdbc URL if your settings above are correct.

P.S. In your JDBC URL you don't have username and password usually it looks like this:

```
jdbc:mysql://<username>:<password>@<hostname>:<port>/<database>
```